# What is the difference between Google cloud disks type for compute engine instances setup?

Tags: user-profile-disks

Does anybody know what these mean with Google cloud? Not sure what this means:

1.Standard persistent disks (pd-standard) are backed by standard hard disk drives (HDD).

2.Balanced persistent disks (pd-balanced) are backed by solid-state drives (SSD). They are an alternative to SSD persistent disks that balance performance and cost.

3.SSD persistent disks (pd-ssd) are backed by solid-state drives (SSD).

Are these disks for backups or what the machine will run on? I mean, if you look at standard disk, that's HDD, no way you can run a website on that? Are these backup disks or will the website sit on them? This is what I HOPE, this means?

- Standard persistent disks = Website runs on SSD, maybe an NVME, and the backup runs on HDD
- Balanced persistent disks = Website runs on SSD, maybe an NVME, and the backup runs on an hybrid HDD/SSD
- SSD persistent disks = Website runs on SSD, maybe an NVME, and the backup runs on an SSD Can anybody confirm what this actually means?

Is there any difference between these options to host basic wordpress sites with little traffic?

Answer (score 2):

Gcp as other cloud providers simply offers you different kind of disks for vms. They have increased price for increased perf.
Nothing prevents you to use any of these disks. And these are the disks used by your vm to run. Just like a pc can have different disk types (hdd, ssd, nvme).

The disk type has nothing to do with the backup, which is usually performed by a snapshot. Maybe automated by a snapshot policy.

The performance required by your Vm should be the driver for your choice, it is just a matter of load testing it and check if the disk i/o is the bottleneck or if the selected disk is ok. There is no silver bullet here.

Just consider this: you can not convert a disk, to change disk you have to snapshot it with the Vm shutdown and recreate a new disk from the snap, selecting a different disk type.